# Method name must be a string fatal error class

Tags: php

How can I fix this code? When I run check.php I get this error:

> Erorr : Fatal error: Method name must be a string in C:\AppServ\www\Weboo\cms\check.php on line 46

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    class mysql {


        private $localhost = "localhost";
        private $db_user = "root";
        private $db_pass = "root";
        private $db_name ="webocms";


        function __construct(){

        mysql_connect($this-> localhost,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        }

    }

    function sql(){

        $username = $_POST ['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username'
         AND password='$password'";

         $query = mysql_query($sql);

         $num = mysql_num_rows($query);

         if ($num > 1){

            $_SESSION['username'] = "username";
            $_SESSION['password'] = "password";

            header("Location: admin/admin.php");
         }else {

            echo "<h2><b> No Users </h2></b>";
         }
    }

    $use=new mysql;
    $use->$sql();
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked if there's anything strange with line number 46?

Comment: `$sql` is a variable..... does it contain a string value? Is that string value the name of a method? Or did you mean `$use->sql();`.... except that `sql()` is simply a global function, not a method in your `mysql` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark said in the comments, I think it should be more like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    class mysql {

        private $localhost = "localhost";
        private $db_user = "root";
        private $db_pass = "root";
        private $db_name ="webocms";

        function __construct(){
            mysql_connect($this-> localhost,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            mysql_select_db($this->db_name);
        }

        function sql(){

            $username = $_POST ['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='$username'
                AND password='$password'";

            $query = mysql_query($sql);

            $num = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($num > 1){

                $_SESSION['username'] = "username";
                $_SESSION['password'] = "password";

                header("Location: admin/admin.php");
            } else {

                echo "<h2><b> No Users </h2></b>";
            }
        }
    }


    $use=new mysql;
    $use->sql();
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Notice, the sql() function is now inside your class and the 2nd to last line is `$use->sql()` not `$use->$sql()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a mistake with the closing brace of your `mysql` class. `sql()` is a function and not a method of the `mysql` class. You're also using a variable which in my opinion appears unintentional.

Instead it should be `$use->sql();` but again that won't work until you put `sql()` inside the class.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysql::sql() in C:\AppServ\www\Weboo\cms\check.php on line 46

Comment: It's not working because you haven't yet moved the `sql` method, that's currently a regular function, inside your `mysql` class.